# Stacking Images in a Python graph

Tags: python, performance, image-processing, 3d

I'm looking to take several 2D images, and put them together back to back to create a sort of pseudo-3D cube, taking advantage of opacity to create depth.

I want to do this in the most efficient way possible, allowing upwards of 400 large images to be stacked in this manner, while at the same time being able to rotate and examine the resulting pseudo-cube. Any ideas?

All these images currently exist as individual data points in a 2D array, so format is not an issue, as long as I can control RGB and alpha.

Comment: What plotting / graphics libraries are you currently using in Python?

Comment: I'm currently using matplotlib, but I can import anything that Pycharm knows how to play nice with